# subchild class inheriting from parent class of non declared function in child class

Tags: c++

I have this condition where I am inheriting from a child class.

Parent >> Child >> SubChild

In SubChild I am editing two functions, one of them **func1**is having some other functionalities in Parent and Child and this is working properly using all functionalities of the three classes.

The other function **func2** is only having functionalities in Parent so in order to exploit Parent functionalities in SubChild I did this solution by adding a declaration  in Child.

```
class Parent
{
  protected:
    virtual void func1() override; 
    virtual void func2(type *Pointer) override;
...
};

class Child : public Parent
{
  protected:
    virtual void func1() override; 
    virtual void func2(type *Pointer) override {Parent::func2(Pointer);}; 

class SubChild: public Child {
protected:
    virtual void func1() override;  
    virtual void func2(type *Pointer) override; 
...
};
```

Actually my error is related to inheritance of first line in func2 but might include other reasons related to Omnet++ in which I am going to ask another question for it. But I want to clear this step by asking this question.

**Is this the right way to make it work or I am violating some rules of coding?**

**edit:** removed the type and * from

`virtual void func2(type *Pointer) override {Parent::func2(type *Pointer);};`

Comment: Is `func2` a member of `Parent`?  You should not have `type*` in the function call `Parent::func2(Pointer);`

Comment: When you declare something as `override` you should actually be intending to override a function in the base class. If none such function exists, you'll get an error. So unless `Parent` derives from yet another Base that defines `func1` and `func2`, you're in trouble.

Comment: `virtual void foo(...) override`? Which is it, virtual or an override? overrides are already virtual. `virtual` should only go on the original declaration. Which version of c++ are you compiling against?

Comment: A couple of unrelated things: If you declare a member function as being `virtual`, that `virtual` declaration follows along when you override in child classes. You don't need the `virtual` keyword there. And in the base class (`Parent` in your example) you don't override the function, so should not declare them using the `override` keyword.

Comment: @aschepler you are right I edited it in the code and forgot it here.

Comment: Also, WHAT error are you getting?

Comment: There is no need for `Child::func2` to exist. Just remove it.

Comment: @Andy good point and yes Parent inherit from another class for func2, so this means it is not possible to do such an inheritance or there might be another method?

Comment: @DavidLively Omnet++ Currently using  C++11 so override is supported and it is actually used existing functions. To mention the error I have to change the question to be omnet++ related as I mentioned which I am going to ask in new question. With this question I just want to make sure that this is wrong or right way of inheritance.

Comment: @Mour_Ka: I mean, your code is technically correct then, however there's no point in overriding a function if you'll simply forward the call onto the parent anyway.

Comment: @KarstenKoop and AndyG I think you mean I should remove the declaration of func2 in child class as no need for it to override. Well I just removed it and you are correct no difference with out it.